# Don't work loop on bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

I have written script on bash. It got all list of interfaces. And in loop has compared with variable. But it doesn't work good.
My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

search=`ls -1 /sys/class/net | grep -v lo`
echo $search

eth=eno1
echo $eth

for i in $search; do
if [ $i == $eth ]; then
echo "You choose is: $i"
else
echo "not found"
fi
done
```

In result i have had:

```
dummy0 eno1 enp4s0 virbr0 virbr0-nic
eno1
not found
You choose is: eno1
not found
not found
not found
```

It is ok. I want, to get one message "You choose is: eno1". If $eth does not 
contains in "/sys/class/net", i want to get message "not found". Where i have mistake ? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the whole loop with one if statement like this:

```
if [[ "$eth" =~ "$search" ]];then
    echo "You choose is: $eth"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

And the whole script in a much compact way:

```
#!/bin/bash
eth=eno1
if [ -d /sys/class/net/$eth ];then
    echo "You choose is: $eth"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: i am sorry, but it doesn't work. i have in result: 
dummy0 eno1 enp4s0 virbr0 virbr0-nic
eno1
You choose is: dummy0
You choose is: eno1
You choose is: enp4s0
You choose is: virbr0
You choose is: virbr0-nic
I need to get one result

Comment: sorry, i've swapped your variables. corrected.

Comment: i have in all interation this output: + [[ eno1 =~ dummy0
eno1
enp4s0
virbr0
virbr0-nic ]]
+ echo 'not found'
not found